# Team Foundation Server 2015 MsBuild 14

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I am getting the following Conflict which doesn't make sense:

> 2>ResolveAssemblyReferences:
>
> No way to resolve conflict
>   between "System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" and "System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35". Choosing
>   "System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" arbitrarily.
>
> No way to resolve conflict
>   between "System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" and "System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35". Choosing
>   "System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" arbitrarily.
>
> Consider app.config
>   remapping of assembly "System.Web.Mvc, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" from Version "5.2.0.0" [] to Version
>   "5.2.3.0"
>   [C:\BuildAgent_work\1\s\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Mvc.dll]
>   to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
>
> [warning]C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5):
>   Warning MSB3247: Found conflicts between different versions of the
>   same dependent assembly. In Visual Studio, double-click this warning
>   (or select it and press Enter) to fix the conflicts; otherwise, add
>   the following binding redirects to the "runtime" node in the
>   application configuration file:

The solution has 3 project and they all use Version=5.2.3.0. When i run local in Visual Studio I don't get this warning.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: What kind of projects are you building? Have you seen this issue before? Do you use XAML build or vNext build? If you build the solution on the build agent machine locally, can you get a successful build? If you are using vNext build, which steps are you using?

Comment: On my local machine I use VS2015. On TFS i use an Agent.  The build is successful on both (on local machine i don't get this warning but on TFS I get it), but i am trying to remove all warning from the build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your issue is because the assembly on your local machine and build agent machine are different. You can try to remove/uninstall the assemblies and reinstall them from Manage Nuget Packages, the warning should disappear.

Comment: You can try to remove the assemblies in your project, and reinstall them from Manage Nuget Packages, when you queue a vNext build, select the checkbox "Restore NuGet Packages". Or you can try to restore the package by following the article http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/team-build

Comment: I had the wrong version of VS. Uninstall 2013 and install 2015 and everything is working.